# Rails 3.2 Where and how to require zip library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2.11. I need to require the ails zip library but can't figure out how to do it. Here is my code which I need only in a single action in a controller.

```
  file_name = "natfiles.zip"
  t = Tempfile.new("temp_natfiles")
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |z|

      z.put_next_entry('NAT00010')
      z.print IO.read("tmp/nat00010")

  end
  send_file t.path, :type => 'application/zip',
                         :disposition => 'attachment',
                         :filename => file_name
  t.close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Gemfile, add a line

```
gem "rubyzip", :require => 'zip/zip'
```

Then run `bundle install`. It will be available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can require it just before you use it. In your case you can require it in your relavent controller. :)